# JS registration form not submitting all information to MYSQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to create a registration and login form using JS, PHP and MQSQL. My login form works but when I register the information only the id, username and password is coming up in the database.

[image: database currently]

I'm not sure why gender, weight, height and email aren't?

my code includes;
a html form

```
<form role="form" id="signform">
  <img src="img/regpic.jpg" alt="reg" id="reg">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="susername" id="susername" type="text" autofocus>
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="spassword" id="spassword" type="password">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="semail" type="text">
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Gender" name="gender" id="sgender" type="text">

  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Weight (kg)" name="weight" id="sweight" type="text">
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Height (inches)" name="height" id="sheight" type="text">
  </div><br>
  <button type="button" id="signupbutton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> <span id="signtext">Sign Up</span></button>
</form>
```

a signup php file;

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    if(isset($_POST['susername'])){
        $username=$_POST['susername'];
        $password=$_POST['spassword'];
        $email=$_POST['semail'];
        $gender=$_POST['sgender'];
        $weight=$_POST['sweight'];
        $height=$_POST['sheight'];

        $query=$conn->query("select * from user where username='$username'");

        if ($query->num_rows>0){
            ?>
                <span>Username already exist.</span>
            <?php 
        }

        elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/",$username)){
            ?>
                <span style="font-size:11px;">Invalid username. Space & Special Characters not allowed.</span>
            <?php 
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/",$password)){
            ?>
                <span style="font-size:11px;">Invalid password. Space & Special Characters not allowed.</span>
            <?php 
        }

        else{
            $mpassword=md5($password);
            $conn->query("insert into user (username, password, email, gender, weight, height) values ('$username', '$mpassword', '$email', '$gender', '$weight', '$height')");
            ?>
                <span>Sign up Successful.</span>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

a login php file

```
<?php 
    include('conn.php');
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);
        $weight=$_POST['weight'];
        $height=$_POST['height'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];

        $query=$conn->query("select * from user where username='$username', password='$password', gender='$gender', email='$email', weight='$weight', height='$height'");

        if ($query->num_rows>0){
            $row=$query->fetch_array();
            $_SESSION['user']=$row['userid']; 
        }
        else{
            ?>
                <span>Login Failed. User not Found.</span>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

and my js file;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //bind enter key to click button
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      if ($('#loginform').is(":visible")) {
        $("#loginbutton").click();
      } else if ($('#signupform').is(":visible")) {
        $("#signupbutton").click();
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#signupbutton', function() {
    if ($('#susername').val() != '' && $('#spassword').val() != '' && $('#semail').val() != '' && $('#sgender').val() != '' && $('#sweight').val() != '' && $('#sheight').val() != '') {
      $('#signtext').text('Signing up...');
      $('#myalert').slideUp();
      var signform = $('#signform').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://cs1.ucc.ie/~lmm12/pjt/signup.php',
        data: signform,
        success: function(data) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myalert').slideDown();
            $('#alerttext').html(data);
            $('#signtext').text('Sign up');
            $('#signform')[0].reset();
          }, 4000);
          window.location.href = "index.html";

        }
      });
    } else {
      alert('Please input both fields to Sign Up');
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#loginbutton', function() {
    if ($('#username').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '') {
      $('#logtext').text('Logging in...');
      $('#myalert').slideUp();
      var logform = $('#loginForm').serialize();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://cs1.ucc.ie/~lmm12/pjt/login.php',
          data: logform,
          success: function(data) {
            if (data == '') {
              $('#myalert').slideDown();
              $('#alerttext').text('Login Successful. User Verified!');
              $('#logtext').text('Login');
              $('#loginForm')[0].reset();
              setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "menu.html";
              }, 2000);
            } else {
              $('#myalert').slideDown();
              $('#alerttext').html(data);
              $('#logtext').text('Login');
              $('#logform')[0].reset();
            }
          }
        });
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      alert('Please input both fields to Login');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements rather than variable substitution. And MD5 should not be used for passwords, use PHP's `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show in signup.php?